# JSTree create_node not working

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to create a new node inside a node when you click on its last children.

I tried the following script, but it always returns false instead of the new node id.

```
$('#categories').jstree().create_node('#', 'Foo');
```

This is the same code with a different syntax, but this isn't working either:

```
$('#categories').jstree().create_node('#', {data:'Foo'});
```

And these are also the same:

```
$('#categories').jstree('create_node', '#', {data:'Foo'});
$('#categories').jstree('create_node', '#', 'Foo');
```

Comment: Just checking that your last example has a typo: "create_noe" instead of "create_node". Is this in your actual code or just because you wrote the question incorrectly?

Comment: I not copied it from my code. I just mistyped it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `"check_callback": true` to your tree config like below.

Check demo - [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/6y9wkwht/).

```
$("#categories").jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": ...,
        "check_callback": true
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it's give back the new item ID but it's not showed in the tree.

Comment: Please clarify that. Don't you see a new node added to the end of the tree?

Comment: No, I don't see, but it's return the newly created node's ID after I placed the check_callback attribute into the initialization options.

Comment: In the demo from my answer, if you follow the link, you will see the new node being added to the end of the tree. The code in the demo is pretty straightforward. On the other hand I can see only a small part of your code. Can you show more of that?

Comment: Excuse me, yesterday after I modified the initialization options, I just tried out the node creation through console, not throught my actual script. And now I see it's working fine in the live code. Thank you so much for the answer and excuse me to robbed your time.

Comment: No worries, glad I helped!